# App install tracking from Gemini/Facebook using Firebase

Tags: android, ios, facebook, firebase

Both of my apps uses Firebase SDK and I'm going to run an app install campaign on Yahoo Gemini and Facebook. I noticed that Gemini and Facebook aren't supported ad networks on Firebase, so I cant create postback/tracking links directly from the platform.

Is there a way to create a custom tracking link on Firebase so I can measure my campaigns metrics from each channel separated?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: any update on this?